# Compilation error while using reduce() and std::execution in C++

Tags: c++, c++17

I am trying to implement a simple use-case `reduce()` and `std:: execution`. I am using C++ 17 standard for the following code. However, the following code still does not get compiled.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <numeric>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
#include <execution>

int main() {
    std:: vector<int> vec(10);
    std:: iota(std::begin(vec), std::end(vec), 1);
    const auto result = std::reduce(std::execution::par, std::begin(vec),
            std::end(vec));
    std:: cout << result;
    return 0;
}
```

### Error:

```
C:\Users\Blind1729\Desktop>g++ --std=c++17 a.cpp
a.cpp: In function 'int main()':
a.cpp:8:25: error: 'reduce' is not a member of 'std'
    const auto result = std::reduce(std::execution::par, std::begin(vec),
                        ^
a.cpp:8:42: error: 'std::execution' has not been declared
    const auto result = std::reduce(std::execution::par, std::begin(vec),
```

Comment: `std::reduce` is in `<numeric>`

Comment: Still does not work, try the code.

Comment: What version of g++ are you using ? *Standardization of Parallelism TS P0024R2 9.x* You have to have at least 9.x of G++. See [reference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/compiler_support)

Comment: C:\Users\Blind1729>g++ --version
g++ (tdm64-1) 5.1.0 
Is this the right one for that code?

Comment: GCC 5.1 was released in 2015, a bit old for C++17

Comment: Oh, got it. Though I used MSVC 2019 also, it still did not work?

Comment: You're using non-standard compiler extensions, which means you need to pay special close attention to your compiler version and your platform. You'll have to upgrade your g++ to run this code. EDIT: Nvm, this might no longer be non-standard in the newer C++ standards.

Comment: @rafix07 FWIW, it seems that gcc9.3 [still has issues](https://wandbox.org/permlink/IPIpCoQcaz4ndyh0) with it (or may be GCC was not built correctly on wandbox).

Comment: @IgorR. You cannot rely on online compiler, with godbolt compiles fine, but there is not library in linking to build final exe, [link godbolt](https://godbolt.org/z/tTtUaY). In libraries Intel TBB is added as external lib.

Comment: @IgorR. When you hover over 9.x (as G++) in feature C++ *Standardization of Parallelism TS* there is being displayed *requires linking with -ltbb*.

Comment: Compiles and runs fine here, using gcc 9.2.1 with `g++ --std=c++17 reduce.cc -ltbb`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to link against TBB, as it is a dependence of the parallel STD (see 
[C++17 STL Parallel Algorithms - with GCC 9.1 and Intel TBB on Linux and macOS](https://solarianprogrammer.com/2019/05/09/cpp-17-stl-parallel-algorithms-gcc-intel-tbb-linux-macos/)):

```
g++ --std=c++17 a.cpp -ltbb
```

And make sure you have at least GCC 9.1 installed.